# Происхождение слова "кокошник"

Tags: этимология

Казалось бы, кокошник - это символ русской традиционной одежды и вообще всего русского, но слово само по себе совершенно не понятное. Мне бы хотелось узнать его происхождение. С чем оно связано? На ум приходит только "куриная" ассоциация ("ко-ко"), потому что по форме он похож на гребень. Но, скорее всего, я ошибаюсь.
Буду признателен за разъяснение этимологии слова "кокошник".

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему ж ошибаетесь? Не ошибаетесь, Фасмер и Даль подтверждают:"вид женского головного убора", производное от ко́кошь "курица" и "петух". Названо так по сходству с гребнем на голове птицы;

Даль: кокошник: - кокуй м. кокошко ж. костр. (от коковка? от кокош?) народный головной убор руских женщин, в виде опахала или округлого щита вкруг головы. Кика и сорока носятся только замужними, делаются из лубка, кузовком, а кокошник носят и девицы: это легонькийвеер из толстой бумаги, пришитый к шапочке или волоснику; он состоит из убраного начельника и донца, или начельника и волосинка, со спуском позади ленты. Вот тебе кокуй, с ним и ликуй! говор. молодой. | Кокошкик, у зодчих, полукруглые щиты, на стенах и на сводах церквей, обычно с писаными образами. | Кокуй, день, праздник Купалы, игрища. Кокошить и пр.               
 http://v-dal.ru/word_s-40779.html

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно согласен с определением на картинке. Но позволю себе не согласиться с Фесмером и Далем. Они исходят из ассоциации с гребнями кур, но слово не так просто.
По моим "исследованиям" любое слово, имеющее более двух-трех звуков, является сложением нескольких морфем(лексем). (Прошу прощения). Древние люди, давая названия окружающим предметам, действиям, явлениям обходились простыми звукосочетаниями, которые в дальнейшем соединялись с другими и образовывали слова, привычные нам сейчас. Пример: кора. Древние заметили, что лишенная наружной шкурки растение высыхает, погибает. Значит шкурка защищает растение от палящих лучей Солнца. Кора - защита от солнца. Солнце, как известно, древние именовали Ра. Значит на ко достается защита. Вернемся к кокошнику. Череп - защита мозгов от...(см. определение возле картинки), т.е. ко. А двойная защита будет коко. Ну, шник - это принадлежность к свойству (двоешник, бумажник и пр.). Резон?

Answer (score 0):

Слово кокошник произошло от сербского Кокошка - курица. Это слово вошло в современный русский язык во времена его становления, то есть в 17 веке. Тогда очень много сербских православных священников были призваны российским престолом для поселения и службы в сёлах центральной России. И сербы принесли много своих слов.